# Posting a file from ASP.NET MVC 4.6 application to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, httppostedfilebase

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application using in the .NET Framework 4.6.

I need to be able to upload files and then forward them to a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API.

The problem is I can't figure out how to send files from the client app to the API.

The API accepts a request like so:

```
public class ReportUploadRequest
{
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
}
```

and the ASP.NET MVC application has a controller function that accepts a form submission and attempts to post to the API.

The files from the form are received in ASP.NET MVC like so:

```
HttpPostedFileBase[] Files
```

I cannot work out how to convert the `HttpPostedFileBase[] Files` files to the `List<IFormFile> Files` format required by the Web API.

I have tried to receive the files in my controller using `List<IFormFile> Files` but `Files` is null on submission

How do I prepare my form to be consumed in a format agreeable to the Web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not ***sure*** that this is what you are asking for but I think it might be.  I have found as long as I can get something into and out of binary, then I am golden.  This also provides me with good interoperability with other languages like C+++.

If not what you are asking.. tell me and I will delete my answer.

This is what I did.  I specifically needed binary data to be passed to my controller and binary data returned.

For my use case, the secret was in ***application/octet-stream***.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeDangController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/octet-stream")]
    public async Task<Stream> GetBinaryThingy()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await reader.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);

                var buffer = ms.ToArray();
                //buffer now holds binary data from the client
            }
       }
       byte[] bytes_return = null  //populate your binary return here.
       return new MemoryStream(bytes_return);
   }
}
```

And on the client.. something like this:

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> PostBinaryStuffAsync(byte[] buffer)
    {
        ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(dangServerURL, byteContent);

        var responseBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        return responseBytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to be able to upload files and then forward them to a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API.

To achieve your requirement, you can refer to the following code snippet.

*In ASP.NET MVC controller action*

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        formContent.Add(new StreamContent(file.InputStream), "files", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

    }

    var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync("https://xxxx/xxxx/UploadFile", formContent);

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //...
    }
```

*In ASP.NET Core action method*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm]List<IFormFile> files)
{
    //...
```

Test Result

[image]